# How to save a checkbox state in database?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am trying to save a checkbox state in my database and retrieve it later but it doesn't seem to work.  I get now errors in my log and am hoping some one would be able to assist.

Here is my code for my checkbox:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/check1"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAge"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/check2"
        android:text="test2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />
```

Then in my CreateOrEditJobCards.java:

```
checkA = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
    checkA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checked)
            {
                SaveString="Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                SaveString="No";
            }
        }
    });
    checkB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check2);
    checkB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checked)
            {
                SaveStringA="Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                SaveStringA="No";
            }
        }
    });

......

if(personID > 0) {
        saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Cursor rs = dbHelper.getPerson(personID);
        rs.moveToFirst();
        String personName = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PERSON_COLUMN_NAME));
        String personGender = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER));
        SaveString = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PERSON_CHECKBOX_A));
        SaveStringA = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PERSON_CHECKBOX_B));
        int personAge = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PERSON_COLUMN_AGE));
        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
            rs.close();
        }

        nameEditText.setText(personName);
        nameEditText.setFocusable(false);
        nameEditText.setClickable(false);

        genderEditText.setText(personGender);
        genderEditText.setFocusable(false);
        genderEditText.setClickable(false);

        ageEditText.setText((personAge + ""));
        ageEditText.setFocusable(false);
        ageEditText.setClickable(false);

        checkA.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(SaveString)));
        checkA.setFocusable(false);
        checkA.setClickable(false);

        checkB.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(SaveStringA)));
        checkB.setFocusable(false);
        checkB.setClickable(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveButton:
            persistPerson();
            return;
        case R.id.editButton:
            saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nameEditText.setEnabled(true);
            nameEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            nameEditText.setClickable(true);

            genderEditText.setEnabled(true);
            genderEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            genderEditText.setClickable(true);

            ageEditText.setEnabled(true);
            ageEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            ageEditText.setClickable(true);

            checkA.setEnabled(true);
            checkA.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            checkA.setClickable(true);

            checkB.setEnabled(true);
            checkB.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            checkB.setClickable(true);


            return;
        case R.id.deleteButton:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deletePerson)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dbHelper.deletePerson(personID);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobCardMainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Delete Job Card?");
            d.show();
            return;
    }
}

public void persistPerson() {
    if(personID > 0) {
        if(dbHelper.updatePerson(personID,
                nameEditText.getText().toString(),
                genderEditText.getText().toString(),
                checkA.getText().toString(),
                checkB.getText().toString(),

                Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString()))) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Card Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobCardMainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Card Update Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(dbHelper.insertPerson(nameEditText.getText().toString(),
                genderEditText.getText().toString(),
                checkA.getText().toString(),
                checkB.getText().toString(),

                Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Card Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not Insert Job Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobCardMainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

And in my DBHelper.java

```
public static final String PERSON_TABLE_NAME = "person";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_AGE = "age";
public static final String PERSON_CHECKBOX_A = "checka";
public static final String PERSON_CHECKBOX_B = "checkb";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_CHECKBOX_A + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_CHECKBOX_B + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_AGE + " INTEGER)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPerson(String name,
                            String gender,
                            String checka,
                            String checkb,
                            int age) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_CHECKBOX_A, checka);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_CHECKBOX_B, checkb);

    db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updatePerson(Integer id,
                            String name,
                            String gender,
                            String checka,
                            String checkb,
                            int age) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_CHECKBOX_A, checka);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_CHECKBOX_B, checkb);
    db.update(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deletePerson(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(PERSON_TABLE_NAME,
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public Cursor getPerson(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}

public Cursor getAllPersons() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null );
    return res;
}
}
```

Basically in this app the user would select "add new jobcard" then would fill in the form and hit save.  This then is displayed in a list view in number order.
When the user would then select the form created earlier they can then hit send and it will then email the form (I am still working on that and code is not in above)

However like I said earlier, everything else in the form works and saves but can't seem to get the checkbox to save the state it was checked

Could some one please have a look at mu code and point out where I have gone wrong and assist?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Log Output:

```
10-29 10:37:13.329 11748-11825/com.software.example D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-29 10:37:13.331 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
10-29 10:37:13.367 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
10-29 10:37:13.367 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-29 10:37:13.370 11748-11748/com.software.example V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3e5e501 nm : com.software.example ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@46effa6
10-29 10:37:13.370 11748-11748/com.software.example I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-29 10:37:13.380 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=96
10-29 10:37:13.380 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=91
10-29 10:37:13.406 11748-11825/com.software.example D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7cfa738000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7cfea52600
10-29 10:37:13.536 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) or=1
10-29 10:37:13.557 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
10-29 10:37:14.180 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-29 10:37:14.261 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-29 10:37:15.057 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-29 10:37:15.156 11748-11748/com.software.exampleD/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-29 10:37:15.807 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-29 10:37:15.975 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-29 10:37:16.544 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-29 10:37:16.619 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-29 10:37:16.697 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=87
10-29 10:37:16.698 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@89b4657[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{7d5a544 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
10-29 10:37:16.710 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-29 10:37:16.712 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@a20a45c[JobCardMainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-29 10:37:16.716 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=88
10-29 10:37:16.735 11748-11825/com.software.example D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [652x176]-format:1
10-29 10:37:16.752 11748-11748/com.software.example D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-29 10:37:16.753 11748-11748/com.software.example D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@17a4e86
10-29 10:37:16.753 11748-11748/com.software.example D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6a47347
10-29 10:37:16.753 11748-11748/com.software.example D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6a47347
10-29 10:37:16.776 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=95
10-29 10:37:16.776 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: setView = DecorView@308d1f8[JobCardMainActivity] touchMode=true
10-29 10:37:16.836 11748-11825/com.software.example D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-29 10:37:16.837 11748-11748/com.software.example D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
10-29 10:37:16.838 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@89b4657[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
10-29 10:37:16.878 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
10-29 10:37:16.878 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-29 10:37:16.879 11748-11748/com.software.example V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5f515a4 nm : com.software.example ic=null
10-29 10:37:16.879 11748-11748/com.software.example I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-29 10:37:16.883 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=104
10-29 10:37:16.883 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=96
10-29 10:37:16.902 11748-11825/com.software.example D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7cce563400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7d0c2ed3a0
10-29 10:37:16.908 11748-11748/com.software.example W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-29 10:37:16.909 11748-11748/com.software.example W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-29 10:37:17.308 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@db7b317[CreateOrEditJobCards]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-29 10:37:17.312 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=85
10-29 10:37:17.665 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-29 10:37:17.670 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@89b4657[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-29 10:37:17.675 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=87
10-29 10:37:17.742 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-29 10:37:17.847 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@3e9255b[JobCardMainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-29 10:37:17.909 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=87
10-29 10:37:17.909 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@ceedbd2[CreateOrEditJobCards]: setView = DecorView@f19c4a3[CreateOrEditJobCards] touchMode=true
10-29 10:37:17.939 11748-11825/com.software.example D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-29 10:37:17.941 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
10-29 10:37:17.967 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@ceedbd2[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
10-29 10:37:17.967 11748-11748/com.software.example D/ViewRootImpl@ceedbd2[CreateOrEditJobCards]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-29 10:37:17.968 11748-11748/com.software.example V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7f1dc85 nm : com.software.example ic=null
10-29 10:37:17.968 11748-11748/com.software.example I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-29 10:37:17.973 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=93
10-29 10:37:17.973 11748-11748/com.software.example D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=104
10-29 10:37:18.000 11748-11825/com.software.example D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7cea5c2c00 (ListView) with handle 0x7d0c26c780
```

Comment: Kindly share the errors you are getting

Comment: Am not getting errors, the log shows nothing that would hint where I am making a mistake.

Comment: share the complete log

Comment: Please see log file under EDIT

Comment: Since SQLite offers no boolean datatype, you must save an integer value, instead. Tipically, you'd use 0 for false an 1 for true. Or you can use any other convention you find logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass checkA.getText().toString() in your insert/update methods, you never change these. Simply pass the SaveStrings (that you alter in your onCheckedChangedListeners) in the dbHelper.insertPerson method:

```
dbHelper.insertPerson(nameEditText.getText().toString(),
            genderEditText.getText().toString(),
            SaveString,
            SaveStringA,
            Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString())))
```

Consider changing the logic a bit to be able to remove a LOT of code.

```
dbHelper.insertPerson(nameEditText.getText().toString(),
            genderEditText.getText().toString(),
            checkA.isChecked() ? "Yes" : "No",
            checkB.isChecked() ? "Yes" : "No",
            Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString())))
```

Then, you can get rid of both the onCheckedChangedListener methods, and the SaveString and SaveStringA references.

ONE OTHER MISTAKE I SEE.....

You have `checkA.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(SaveString)));`  .. I don't think parseBoolean works correctly for "Yes" "No"... needs "True" "False", so it's never going to retrieve the correct check state until you change this. So either alter the insertPerson method to this:

```
checkA.isChecked() ? "True" : "False"
checkB.isChecked() ? "True" : "False"
```

Or, alter your setChecked to this:

```
checkA.setChecked(SaveString.equals("Yes"));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate your help.  It is working perfectly now :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you're persisting the Person object you are saving what's returned by checkbox.getText() and not the SaveString object where you are storing the checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

I used string as yes and no for the checkbox status and then saved it database.
Also I am detecting the back button when pressed and saving the status of checkbox at the time when app is about to close only to avoid continuous spam in database.
I am attaching my complete code. Hope this solves your problem.
Also I used different java files for everything to avoid confusion.

TaskContract.java

```
public class TaskContract {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "com.pkr.checkbox";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE = "checkbox";
        public static final String HI_CHECK = "hi_checkbox";
        public static final String HELLO_CHECK = "hello_checkbox";
    }
}
```

TaskDBHelper.java

```
public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public TaskDBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.HI_CHECK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.HELLO_CHECK + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        String defaultEntry = "INSERT INTO " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " (" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.HI_CHECK + "," + TaskContract.TaskEntry.HELLO_CHECK + ") VALUES\n" +
            "('No','No');";

        db.execSQL(createTable);
        db.execSQL(defaultEntry);
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CheckBox hi_checkbox_but;
    private CheckBox hello_checkbox_but;
    private TaskDBHelper mHelper = new TaskDBHelper(this);
    String hi, hello;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hi_checkbox_but = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        hello_checkbox_but = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.HI_CHECK, TaskContract.TaskEntry.HELLO_CHECK},
            null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cur.moveToNext()){
            int hi_index = cur.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.HI_CHECK);
            int hello_index = cur.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.HELLO_CHECK);
            hi = cur.getString(hi_index);
            hello = cur.getString(hello_index);

        }

        if (hi.equals("Yes"))
            hi_checkbox_but.setChecked(true);
        else
            hi_checkbox_but.setChecked(false);

        if (hello.equals("Yes"))
            hello_checkbox_but.setChecked(true);
        else
            hello_checkbox_but.setChecked(false);

    }

    private Boolean exit = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        String hi_toPass, hello_toPass;
        if (exit) {

            if (hi_checkbox_but.isChecked())
                hi_toPass = "Yes";
            else
                hi_toPass = "No";
            if (hello_checkbox_but.isChecked())
                hello_toPass = "Yes";
            else
                hello_toPass = "No";

            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.HI_CHECK,hi_toPass);
            cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.HELLO_CHECK, hello_toPass);
            db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                null,
                cv,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 3 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.pkr.checkbox.MainActivity">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="HI" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```